# Secure Download Manager is stuck

Tags: visual-studio

I'm downloading Visual Studio by Secure Download Manager. It stuck at 70% for a several hours. I've stopped and resumed several times now. Also I've tried to delete and download again .sdx but it starts from exactly the same 70% and doesn't move. How can I start from scratch or make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you havent fingured it out already, to delete the file and start again, there should be a file with the extension .sdc. Delete that and run the SDX again. That should do the trick